# Allow Rails route params to be disordered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have the following route:

```
get "/marflar/:id(/colour/:colour)(/wheels/:wheels), to: "marflar#index"
```

It matches the following urls:

```
/marflar/123
/marflar/123/colour/red
/marflar/123/wheels/4
/marflar/123/colour/red/wheels/4
```

But it forces me to put colour before wheels, i.e. the following does not work:

```
/marflar/123/wheels/4/colour/red
```

How can I stipulate that the order of the matched constraints does not matter?

Comment: Why don't you use parameters in url after question mark? - `get '/marflar/:id', to: 'marflar#index'`. Then just make a request `marflar#index?wheels=4&color=red`

Comment: In case you don't have too many parameters (only color & wheels) you could add one more route - `get "/marflar/:id/wheels/:wheels(/colour/:colour), to: "marflar#index"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to catch part of url into params and somehow parse them after.

According to [Rails Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) you can use *Route Globbing and Wildcard Segments*

Extract from guides, e.g.:

```
get 'photos/*other', to: 'photos#unknown'
```

This route would match `photos/12` or `/photos/long/path/to/12`, setting `params[:other]` to `12` or `long/path/to/12`. The fragments prefixed with a star are called "wildcard segments".

In your case:

```
get "/marflar/:id/*options", to: "marflar#index"
```

Like previous answer this won't catch parameters separately, but you have a choice what to do next.

Comment: Thanks, this is perhaps the best way to go about it. Wish rails had support for this out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

Hope, the following will do:

get "/marflar/:id(/:name_1/:colour)(/:name_2/:wheels)",  constraints: { name_1: /color|wheels/, name_2: /color|wheels/ },  to: "marflar#index"

Please check and let me know.

I would suggest using url like /marflar/:id?color=red&wheels=10.